# Adjacency matrix to show flow conservation in maxflow

Tags: matlab, linear-programming, adjacency-matrix, max-flow

I want to use adjacency matrix in MATLAB to solve a maximum flow problem formulated in Linear Programming. I want to try with adjacency matrix because using incidence matrix gives huge matrices  due to the number of edges.

Comment: The LP matrix will look like an incidence matrix (every column is an arc). The usual trick is to exploit sparsity: (1) only generate variables flow[i,j] if arc i->j exists, (2) the LP matrix is sparse (even for complete graphs) as there are 2 nonzeros per column. For large problems, exploiting sparsity is very important. Matlab has good support for sparse matrices.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment @ErwinKalvelagen, let me try to look at it from that dimension. Thanks